# rails link_to with remote => true and jquery on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have simple question. I use rails link_to like this:

```
link_to 'sometxt', some_path(item), :class=>'fancybox button-click', :remote => true
```

and my question - is it right, to put jQuery on click event for this link ?

```
$('.button-click').on('click',function(){
    //some action
});
```

or it isn't good solution to have link_to with remote and jQuery on click event for one link?

What I want is to append loading gif when user click on link and fancybox showLoading doesn't work good for me so I'm trying other way to put preloader.

Comment: I don't see why it'd be bad. It's just events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!!

I'm not sure about overriding the `click` event (I'm sure it will be fine to bind twice, but I've not got any references)

--

**Ajax**

In regards to calling a `preloader`, you'll want to use [one of the `ajax` hooks](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) that Rails UJS provides:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(".button_click").on("ajax:beforeSend", function(){
    // preloader load
}).on("ajax:complete", function(){
    //preloader hide
});
```

[image]

This will be what you need